# Django - Celery Worker - Channels

Tags: python, django, celery, worker, channel

thank you in advance

I am trying to start a Celery Worker to accept WebConnections usng Channels - but when my worker starts it cannot seem to find channels. When I pip list channels is installed

settings.py has channels

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'channels','
```

tasks.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
import threading
from merlin.celery import app, get_blender
from django.conf import settings
from celery import shared_task
from channels import Channel

@app.task(bind=True, track_started=True)
def render(task, data, reply_channel):
    bpy = get_blender()
    setup_scene(bpy, data)

context = {'rendering': True, 'filepath': os.path.join(settings.BLENDER_RENDER_TMP_DIR, task.request.id)}
sync_thread = threading.Thread(target=sync_render, args=(bpy, context, reply_channel))
sync_thread.start()
bpy.ops.render.render()
context['rendering'] = False
sync_thread.join()

if os.path.exists(context['filepath']):
    os.remove(context['filepath'])

if reply_channel is not None:
    Channel(reply_channel).send({
        'text': json.dumps({
            'action': 'render_finished'
        })
    })'
```

The error I get -

```
from channels import Channel
ImportError: cannot import name 'Channel' from 'channels' 
(/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/channels/__init__.py)
```

Again thank you in advance

Comment: Yes, the package is installed and Python is attempting to import from there; there is no configuration problem. (Sometimes people try to have a file named `channels.py` in their own project, which is imported instead of the library.) The problem, as clearly explained by the error message, is that `Channel` is not a thing that can be `import`ed `from channels`. For problems like this, you should start by trying to *read* and *understand* the error message, and then consult the [documentation](https://channels.readthedocs.io)

Comment: Thank you for the guidance - I did consult the documentation and I did read the error - it was and is a lack of experience and understanding. I have been assuming somehow my worker did not have channels available. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See the documentation for using channel layers outside of consumers](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/channel_layers.html#using-outside-of-consumers)

```
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer
channel_layer = get_channel_layer()

@app.task(bind=True, track_started=True)
def render(task, data, reply_channel):
    ...
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)(reply_channel, {
        'type': 'this_is_required',
        'text': json.dumps({
            'action': 'render_finished'
        })
    })
```

[You may want to consider using channel workers and background tasks](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/worker.html)

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your help I will try this

Comment: @JohnCapobianco channel works may be an alternative to using celery  https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/worker.html

Comment: I want to let you know your advice worked - I have a new error message now - but I am beyond the import issue !! Thank you for your gracious assistance. I really do appreciate your time.